# Socket.io memory doesn't drop of after clients disconnect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
var server = require('socket.io').listen(1781);
server.set('log level', 1);

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(process.memoryUsage());
}, 60000);
```

I have memory leaks in my Socket.io 0.9.16 and Node 0.10.12 / 0.10.13 application.
After connecting some clients the RSS memory increases but after I disconnect them the memory doesn't drop off. I stripped my app down to the upper code to exclude any of my mistakes.
After connecting 1000 clients, the process takes 65MB (initially it took ~15MB) and after I disconnect all clients, the memory stays high. Any help?

All of the articles/answers i read were about earlier versions of node or socket.io. I am desperate to find a solution on this.

Comment: The memory is cleaned up by the garbage collectors periodically.

Comment: I waited half an hour for this. How is this possible?

Comment: 65 mb is not high enough to kick in garbage collectors, garbage collection can slow down the server. Most likely it goes upto a few hundred mbs(this value can be different for different node versions) after which it stays there, as old connections are removed.

Comment: I'll try to consume more memory after connecting the clients. I'll reply with results. Thanks

Comment: @hfcorriez It seems like I was worrying to much. It's like user568109 said. Also, I was testing the app with nodetime, and I noticed that it never stops taking memory. So i ditched nodetime and observed my app only using top -p [nodeprocess]. It was all ok. The memory consumption is stable now.

Comment: @TiberiuMaxim Thank you, I already make a simple test, it's ok. But I see some arguments of socket.io, such as [this](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/issues/438) it has much more problems, how about you using it in production environment?

Comment: Didn't have any of those problems. Anyway, my client is not the browser, but ios/android device.

Comment: You can "help" the garbage colector assigning a null value to your unused vars:

`myUnusedClass = null;`

Comment: @TiberiuMaxim If the question is solved for you can you please answer it yourself and accept it as the accepted answer, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using nodetime for tracking memory usage and it seems like it had a memory leak. After ditching nodetime, the memory consumption was stable.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with socket.io. It seems that once a client connects, it never gets deleted from socket.io.

You can debug the value of SocketIoServer.sockets.sockets. It is an array containing all connected (and disconnected sockets). Maybe that's where your memory leak lies.

Also, I just saw that socket.io released version 1.0. You can try it out and see if it has resolved that issue.

Comment: I checked that and it wasn't happening to me